# JOIN tables on a date range, but show the missing dates?

Tags: sql, db2

I have two tables:

a

| WEEK_DATE | DAY_NUMBER |
| --- | --- |
| 8/17/2022 | 1 |
| 8/18/2022 | 2 |
| 8/19/2022 | 3 |
| 8/22/2022 | 4 |
| 8/23/2022 | 5 |
| 8/24/2022 | 6 |
| 8/25/2022 | 7 |
| 8/26/2022 | 8 |
| 8/29/2022 | 9 |

b

| START_DATE | END_DATE | PERSON |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8/17/2022 | 8/18/2022 | Jack |
| 8/23/2022 | 8/29/2022 | Jack |

I am trying to determine the week days that Jack missed, which would look like this:

| PERSON | WEEK_DATE | DAY_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 8/19/2022 | 3 |
| Jack | 8/22/2022 | 4 |

Right now, this is my query and the results below:

```
SELECT
    b.START_DATE,
    b.END_DATE,
    b.PERSON,
    a.WEEK_DATE,
    a.DAY_NUMBER
FROM b
LEFT JOIN a
    ON a.WEEK_DATE BETWEEN b.START_DATE AND b.END_DATE
```

| START_DATE | END_DATE | PERSON | WEEK_DATE | DAY_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8/17/2022 | 8/18/2022 | Jack | 8/17/2022 | 1 |
| 8/17/2022 | 8/18/2022 | Jack | 8/18/2022 | 2 |
| 8/23/2022 | 8/29/2022 | Jack | 8/23/2022 | 5 |
| 8/23/2022 | 8/29/2022 | Jack | 8/24/2022 | 6 |
| 8/23/2022 | 8/29/2022 | Jack | 8/25/2022 | 7 |
| 8/23/2022 | 8/29/2022 | Jack | 8/26/2022 | 8 |
| 8/23/2022 | 8/29/2022 | Jack | 8/29/2022 | 9 |

How do I get the JOIN to include Jack's missed days as shown previously (days 3 and 4)? Even as nulls like this:

| START_DATE | END_DATE | PERSON | WEEK_DATE | DAY_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8/17/2022 | 8/18/2022 | Jack | 8/17/2022 | 1 |
| 8/17/2022 | 8/18/2022 | Jack | 8/18/2022 | 2 |
| (null) | (null) | Jack | 8/19/2022 | (null) |
| (null) | (null) | Jack | 8/22/2022 | (null) |
| 8/23/2022 | 8/29/2022 | Jack | 8/23/2022 | 5 |
| 8/23/2022 | 8/29/2022 | Jack | 8/24/2022 | 6 |
| 8/23/2022 | 8/29/2022 | Jack | 8/25/2022 | 7 |
| 8/23/2022 | 8/29/2022 | Jack | 8/26/2022 | 8 |
| 8/23/2022 | 8/29/2022 | Jack | 8/29/2022 | 9 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options, either use a `RIGHT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    b.START_DATE,
    b.END_DATE,
    b.PERSON,
    a.WEEK_DATE,
    a.DAY_NUMBER
FROM b
RIGHT JOIN a
    ON a.WEEK_DATE BETWEEN b.START_DATE AND b.END_DATE
--WHERE a.DAY_NUMBER IS NULL
```

Or, swap your table order:

```
SELECT
    b.START_DATE,
    b.END_DATE,
    b.PERSON,
    a.WEEK_DATE,
    a.DAY_NUMBER
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b
    ON a.WEEK_DATE BETWEEN b.START_DATE AND b.END_DATE
--WHERE a.DAY_NUMBER IS NULL
```

I would recommend the second option as pretty much everyone writes SQL to use `LEFT JOIN`s, so they are the more easily understood option.

**EDIT** to add some further explanation:

The only time you'll ever want a `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN` are in cases like these where you need to conserve rows that would be filtered out by an `INNER JOIN`.

If you a look at a basic from/join:

```
FROM table a
JOIN table b
```

The top table a is the left table, the bottom table b is the right table. Same is generally true for later joins:

```
JOIN table a ...
JOIN table b on a.id = b.id
```

Table a is left, table b is right.

So if you want to conserve rows from table a, you would want a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
FROM table a
LEFT JOIN table b
```

If you wanted to conserve rows from table b, then we loop back to your original situation, and you could `RIGHT JOIN`:

```
FROM table a
RIGHT JOIN table b
```

But again, everyone always uses `LEFT JOIN`s as the standard, so you'd be better off swapping the table order and using a left:

```
FROM table b
LEFT JOIN table a
```